# C# и библиотеки из python

Tags: c#, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли у C# библиотека которой можно тоже самое воспроизвести?

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Функции которые нужно воспроизвести

```py
char_to_num = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(characters), mask_token=None
)

num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)


def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]

    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]
  
    output_text = []
    for res in results:
        res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(res)
    return output_text
```

Comment: [TensorFlow.NET](https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ блин, что то я сначала декодер там не нашёл, а сейчас прям сходу. Спасибо!

Comment: @Vipz https://pastebin.com/V4Z3RS1F